# How can I tell which sites I've authorized to access my information on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

How do I know which sites I've allowed to have access to my information on Twitter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to twitter.com
2. Log in.
3. Click on `Settings`
4. Click on `Connections`:

[image: OpenAuthSettings]